# How to use LINQ query using OR condition in join clause

Tags: c#, linq

I have been trying to convert the following SQL into a LINQ to Entity statement:

```
select * from Table1 a 
inner join Table2 on a.Column1 = hr.Column1 OR a.Column1 = hr.Column2
```

However, LINQ does not seem to support the OR operator in JOIN clauses.
Please suggest me the correct way to do it?

Comment: You cannot.  You have to move the logic to the where clause and do a cross join instead. `from a in Table1 from b in Table2 where a.Column1 ==b.Column1 || a.Column1 == b.Column2 select new { A = a, B = b}`

Comment: Examine carefully whether OR is truly what makes sense.. If for example you have Person and they have WorkAddress and HomeAddress, the answer is probably not to do `person join address on homeaddress = address.id OR workaddress = address.id` but instead to do `person p join address wrk on p.workaddressid = wrk.addressid join address hm on p.homeaddressid = hm.addressid` i.e. join address in twice and keep the person-workaddress-homeaddress all related together; using OR will split it to two rows then you have to mess around trying to recombine them to know John's Home and Work address